# "Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories" in react native

Tags: react-native

I have started learning react native. I am struggling in the simple react native project while importing new js [example Home.js] in index.android.js
I'm getting the following error"

> Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories.

UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `.src/Components/home/Home/Home.js` from `C:\Users\Magi\Dictionary1\index.android.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';    
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';    
import Home from '.src/Components/home/Home/Home.js';
```

Comment: The correct one is import Home from './src/Components/home/Home/Home.js'; that means this file is in the same folder where index.android.js is.

Comment: I  tried by changing the import as you said because my Home.js is not in the same folder.eventhough it throwing the same error as ** Unable to resolve module `./src/Components/home/Home/Home.js` from `C:\Users\Magi\Dictionary1\index.android.js`: Directory C:\Users\Magi\Dictionary1\src\Components\home\Home\Home.js doesn't exist**

Answer (score 3):

Some unwanted import can be causing the issue.

For me, this state was creating the issue.

```
import { exec } from "child_process";
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this error when one of my `imports` was pointing to the wrong file.  e.g. `import { API } from './API'` instead of `import { API } from '../utils/API'`

Answer (score 1):

If `Home.js` and `index.android.js` are in the same directory, you can replace

```
import Home from '.src/Components/home/Home/Home.js';
```

with

```
import Home from './Home.js';
```

But if your `src` folder is at the same level as `index.android.js`, `src` needs to be preceded by `./` instead of `.`:

```
import Home from './src/Components/home/Home/Home.js';
```

Comment: I tried your solution    preceded by ./  because my Home.js is not in the same folder.eventhough it throwing the same error as ** Unable to resolve module `./src/Components/home/Home/Home.js` from `C:\Users\Magi\Dictionary1\index.android.js`: Directory C:\Users\Magi\Dictionary1\src\Components\home\Home\Home.js doesn't exist**

Comment: try import Home from  '../src/Components/home/Home/Home.js'  and confirm that you have exported the Home class/component from Home.js.