# react-native error: module does not exist in module map

Tags: react-native

This is the error:
[image: error]

I have tried all of the things in the Github issue, in the error description and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748429), to no avail.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyAppName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "^24.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "expo": "^24.0.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.51.0",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.11",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.0.16",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.0.18",
    "react-native-open-maps": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.22",
    "rn-viewpager": "^1.2.9"
  }
}
```

FOR ANY FUTURE VIEWERS: This was a dependency issue. If you are using version control, copy your old dependencies into your current `package.json`

Comment: remove your node modules folder : `rm-rf node_modules` . Yarn install again .

Comment: I did that already. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a dependency issue. If you are using version control, copy your old dependencies into your current `package.json`

I couldn't figure out what was wrong so I simply re-cloned my project from GitHub and copied my code over.

Comment: This isn't an ANSWER to the question.

Comment: It was the answer for me

Comment: If it was not the answer for you, ask your own question. Don't downvote mine.

Answer (score 0):

Move into your Project folder :

1. *rm -rf node_modules*
2. *npm install*
3. Inside *package.json*. Check if all the modules are present.
4. *react-native start --reset-cache*

Comment: Can you tell which react native version are you using?

Comment: 0.51.0, btw it says in the package.json

Answer (score 0):

For me only downgrade npm from 6.1.0 to 6.0.0 helped: `npm i -g npm@6.0.0`

Comment: That might be a solution. I fixed it already do I can't try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to resolve module  from : Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
We’ve found that this error is generally caused by using wildcards (^ or ~) in your package.json.

Our recommendation is to either remove the wildcards, or to move to using yarn and committing your yarn.lock.